# Slope for Specific Range

Tags: fitting

What I need to do is to have de slope of some data. Ok, I can do that with:

```
Fit[data,{1,x},x]
```

But the thing I need, is to have the slope on the left part of the data crossing the x-axis and then the slope of the right part of the data crossing de x-axis, how can I do that and have the two slopes?

Comment: Then, why not split your data into two groups?

Comment: Splitting the data is usually convenient with something similar to `Cases[data, {x_, y_} /; x > 10]`.

Comment: `FindClusters` may be useful in splitting your data into groups.

Answer (score 4):

Construct some pretend data with a bit of noise:

```
n = 2000;
data1 = {#, #} & /@ RandomReal[1, n];
data2 = {1 + #, 1 - #} & /@ RandomReal[1, n];
data = Join[data1, data2] + RandomReal[0.1, {2 n, 2}];
ListPlot[data]
```

[image]

Obviously this data is very artificial, but the solution should be completely general.

This approach relies on a simple use of `Piecewise`. Define:

```
model = Piecewise[{{a1 + b1 x, x <= c}, {a2 + b2 x, x > c}}, 0];
```

That is, we're going to fit a piecewise linear function, where the cut-off point is parameterized along with the parameters to the two linear functions. I've included two versions: the first (commented) one does not require that the two functions meet at cut-off point. This would be the way to go if your data has a discontinuity when the slope changes. The second includes a constraint to make sure the two functions meet up.

```
(* s = FindFit[data, model, {a1, b1, a2, b2, c}, x] *)
s = FindFit[data, {model, a1 + b1 c == a2 + b2 c}, {a1, b1, a2, b2, c}, x]

(* {a1 -> 0.00241482, b1 -> 0.994713, a2 -> 2.09217, b2 -> -0.995545, c -> 1.05002} *)
```

Plot the result

```
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[model /. s, {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}]]
```

[image]

Should work just as well for sparse or dense data.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** I should mention the following is going to be less than spectacular when there's not a lot of data on *both* sides of the deflection, especially if one of the slopes is shallow.  If the vast majority of your data is sloped up, and only a little bit of data is sloped down and only sloped down a little bit, you might find a better global fit that goes through all your data with just one constant line.  What follows works *best* when there's hefty breadth (not just number of points, but number of points over a descriptive range)  of data on both sides and the slopes are both sharp.

---

Well if it's really linear data that has a phase transition at some point from positive slope to negative slope, and the data isn't too noisy, it doesn't have to be so bad to even find *where* to split the data.

The appropriate functional form for something that changes it's slope discretely at one spot is something like 
$$
f(x)=m_1 (x \theta (x_0-x)+x_0 \theta (x-x_0))+m_2
   (x-x_0) \theta (x-x_0)
$$
where $\theta$ is the Heaviside theta function, well handled numerically with the unit step function `UnitStep`.  So you can fit this function of three parameters to your data, and if it has the expected 2-slope behavior you have a decent chance of ending up fairly close.

Let's see some examples, playing with some fake data in absence of OP providing us with real data.  The game will be we draw some mildly noisy data with two random slopes, and a random point of phase transition.  Then we'll fit and see how well we recover the slopes and transition (switch) point.

---

First let's start with a crazy dense set of data.

```
slopeX1 = RandomReal[{1, 15}];
slopeX2 = RandomReal[{-15, -1}];
switch = RandomReal[{10, 90}];
fauxData = Table[UnitStep[switch - x] ({x, x slopeX1}) +
    UnitStep[
      x - switch] ({ x, switch slopeX1 + (x - switch) slopeX2}) + 
    RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 2], {x, 0, 100, .01}];
ListPlot[fauxData]
```

for my random case gave me:

[image]

We try a naive fit:

```
In[884]:= FindFit[fauxData, UnitStep[sw - x] x m1 +
  UnitStep[x - sw] (sw m1 + (x - sw) m2), {sw, m1, m2}, x]
```

> {sw -> 28.0187, m1 -> 7.41801, m2 -> -1.2941}

And compare with what was in the box:

```
{switch, slopeX1, slopeX2}
```

> {27.7685, 7.53395, -1.32483}

---

Not just a trick of **such** crazy dense data:

```
slopeX1 = RandomReal[{1, 15}];
slopeX2 = RandomReal[{-15, -1}];
switch = RandomReal[{10, 90}];
fauxData = Table[UnitStep[switch - x] ({x, x slopeX1}) +
    UnitStep[
      x - switch] ({ x, switch slopeX1 + (x - switch) slopeX2}) + 
    RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 2], {x, 0, 100, 4}];

ListPlot[fauxData, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

and:

```
 FindFit[fauxData, UnitStep[sw - x] x m1 +
  UnitStep[x - sw] (sw m1 + (x - sw) m2), {sw, m1, m2}, x]
```

> {sw -> 52.2746, m1 -> 2.58171, m2 -> -13.4089}

```
 {switch, slopeX1, slopeX2}
```

> {52.7155, 2.51955, -13.7747}

Comment: If one executes your code with the smaller number of data points for a few times, sometimes the estimates are off because of the starting values that `FindFit` uses.  This can be an issue with just about any regression model.  Selecting the starting value for `switch` to be half-way between the minimum and maximum predictor values is a bit more stable (but certainly not perfect):  `nlm = NonlinearModelFit[fauxData, UnitStep[sw - x] x m1 + UnitStep[x - sw] (sw m1 + (x - sw) m2), {{sw, 50}, m1, m2}, x]`.